# How to fix the ubuntu splash loading bar showing up on the desktop view?

Tags: 16.04, lts

Couldn't get a proper screenshot from the actual issue, but it seems like the animation loop of these dots blinking isn't stopping after the desktop view is loaded.

[image]

These dots are blinking in the middle of the screen

Comment: From the terminal type `systemctl list-units --all plymouth-quit-wait.service`. What is displayed?

Comment: The problem has been solved by disabling the splash screen altogether, but I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short term fix

This is the Plymouth splash screen. As a short term fix you can disable it by editing the file `/etc/default/grub` with `sudo` powers and searching for this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Remove the `splash` parameter so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

**NOTE:** You may have other options besides `quite splash`. Only remove the `splash` option.

Save the file and exit your editor. Then use:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

On the next reboot instead of the purple splash screen with moving dots you'll have a plain black screen instead.

---

### Long term fix

From the terminal use:

```
$ systemctl list-units --all plymouth-quit-wait.service
UNIT                       LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB  DESCRIPTION
plymouth-quit-wait.service loaded inactive dead Hold until boot process finishes up

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Above is the the normal output. Compare yours and report any differences in your question.

Next step is to look for error messages using:

```
$ journalctl -b-1 | grep -i plymouth
Apr 03 05:36:13 alien systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Apr 03 05:36:14 alien systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Apr 03 05:36:14 alien systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Apr 03 05:36:14 alien systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 389 (plymouthd).
Apr 03 05:36:15 alien systemd[1]: Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
Apr 03 05:36:15 alien systemd[1]: Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
Apr 03 05:36:15 alien systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 389 (plymouthd).
Apr 03 05:39:32 alien systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Reboot Screen...
Apr 03 05:39:33 alien systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 20980 (plymouthd).
Apr 03 05:39:33 alien systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Reboot Screen.
Apr 03 05:39:34 alien systemd[1]: Stopped Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
```

Once again the above is normal output.

Comment: The short term fix seemed to have worked, though after a reboot. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a fix.  Disabling the software doesn't fix it and the "long term fix" offers zero advice.

Comment: @BadZen The question was posted over a year ago and the author was not inclined to pursue the problem. You can post a new question with your system details and people will help you work out a solution through a series of trials and corrections (hopefully).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am currently having a simular issue after a move/resize of the boot partition (due to always full) in favor of the efi system partition. In my case, the output of `systemctl list-units --all plymouth-quit-wait.service` shows that the active status is activating and both sub and job say "start". The `journalctl` command says no persistent journal was found. Can I add on this question and would you have some advice or should I open a new question?