# Plymouth loading dots on desktop

Tags: 18.04

I have this loading bar across my screen that look similar to the Plymouth loading dots. They flicker in and out. I saw a post about removing splash from */etc/default/grub* but to no avail.

[image: Dots]

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1021861/248158 & https://askubuntu.com/q/1025946/248158

Comment: Is this a fresh install or an upgrade? Any recent changes to your system?

Comment: Fresh install.  As far as I remember I haven't changed anything in the system

Comment: native or VM? [my problem occurred only in a qemu-VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148998/ubuntu-18-04-qemu-vm-loading-bar-from-start-screen-still-on-desktop)